# Using Regex to Match Pattern Java

Tags: java, regex

I have two lists of words,

A: pit pot spate slaptwo respite,

B: pt Pot peat part

I have to create a regex Pattern that returns true for everything in column A and false for everything in column B. I think there is something I'm fundamentally missunderstanding about regex, because everything I come up with ends up with having one extra false where I don't want it. Mainly I can't seen to figure out how to disallow two vowels next to each other.

Here's what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] check = {"pit","spot","spate","slaptwo","respite","pt","Pot","peat","part"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([psr][^t(ea)][^r])\\w*");

    ArrayList<Matcher> M = new ArrayList<Matcher>();
    for (int i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        M.add(p.matcher(check[i]));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < M.size(); j++){ 
        System.out.println("Return Value:" +check[j] + "\t"+ M.get(j).matches());
    } 
}
```

I understand now that (ea) is not being read as one thing so it causes respite to be false when I don't want it to, everything else returns the correct value. As I said before I need to know how to disallow two vowels being next to each other. Or if I am just missing something fundamental here?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use grouping constructs inside of a character class.

To disallow "ea" you can use Negative Lookahead here.

```
[psr](?!ea)[^t][^r]\\w*
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mT3eI7/1)